# Manage revisions in postgresql

Tags: function, postgresql, triggers, sequence

I am currently trying to manage revisions of a data set in a postgreSql database. The table I would like to use has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE dataset (
   id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   revision INTEGER NOT NULL,
   object_id BIGINT NOT NULL
);
```

The `id` field is a unique auto-increment identifier. The `object_id` should be the identifier for a object, while `revision` keeps track of the revisions:

```
id | object_id | revision
-------------------------
 1 |         1 |        1
 2 |         2 |        1
 3 |         1 |        2
 4 |         1 |        3
 5 |         3 |        1
 6 |         4 |        1
```

What I now need is a function, that:

1. Sets a auto-increment object_id and sets revision to 1, if no object_id is provided.
2. Sets a auto-increment revision for this object_id, if an object_id is provided.

I already found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259158/track-revisions-in-postgresql), but this does not really solve the problem of creating consecutive revisions for a object_id and it does not solve the problem of auto creating consecutive object_ids.

**EDIT:**

I would do something like the following, but this doesn't feel very comfortable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_revision() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF tg_op='INSERT' THEN
        IF NEW.object_id != NULL THEN
            NEW.object_id = SELECT nextval(object_id_seq_id);
            NEW.revision = 1;
        ELSE
            NEW.revision = SELECT MAX(revision)+1 FROM dataset WHERE spot_id = NEW.spot_id;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER update_revision BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON dataset
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_revision();
```

Answer (score 3):

Make `(object_id, revision)` `unique`. BTW why aren't they the `primary key`?

```
create table dataset (
    id bigserial primary key,
    object_id bigint not null,
    revision integer not null,
    unique (object_id, revision)
);

create or replace function include_revision (_object_id integer)
returns dataset as $$
    with object_id as (
        select coalesce(max(object_id), 0) + 1 as object_id
        from dataset
    ), revision as (
        select coalesce(max(revision), 0) + 1 as revision
        from dataset
        where object_id = _object_id
    )
    insert into dataset (object_id, revision)
    select
        coalesce(_object_id, (select object_id from object_id)),
        (select revision from revision)
    returning *
    ;
$$ language sql;
```

`object_id` is set to `coalesce(_object_id, (select object_id from object_id))`, that is, only if `_object_id` is null it will use the calculated `max(object_id)`

Testing:

```
select include_revision(null);
 include_revision 
------------------
 (1,1,1)

select include_revision(1);
 include_revision 
------------------
 (2,1,2)

select include_revision(null);
 include_revision 
------------------
 (3,2,1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I have some problems with this solution. The `dataset` table is a simplified example and would contain more columns. However, I think this could be fixed by using NEW object as I did in my first thoughts!? And I don't see why `object_id` shouldn't be incremented each time you call this function, as you set object_id always to `coalesce(max(object_id), 0) + 1` without testing, if a `_object_id` was given. I see it works, but I don't understand why. And finally I would like to know if this is a fast solution, as I believe to know that `with` is very slow.

Comment: @Avedo `NEW` only exists for trigger functions. I don't think you need it. You can pass the other columns as parameters. Check the updated explanation for `object_id`

Comment: @Avedo Where did you get that `with` is slow? It makes no sense.

Comment: I think it was mentioned in a talk of Peter van Hardenberg `Postgres The Bits You Haven't Found`, but I am not sure. I will have a look at it again. However, using NEW in the example used in my first post works. And I would prefer using a trigger, because I do not need to care about the database implementation details (knowing the fuctions).

Comment: Ok, I watched the talk ([Postgres The Bits You Haven't Found](http://vimeo.com/61044807)) again and he calls the WITH statements ' ... ugly, but damn useful ...', so I was wrong. Sorry. However, I would still prefer a solution, which allows me to insert and update rows as I normally would, while handling all that crazy stuff in background.